# Почему, на некоторых телефонах выводит ошибку таймер?

Tags: javascript

У меня на телефоне все хорошо, у некоторых людей таймер выводит вот это. Что это вообще такое и как с этим бороться? На некоторых все выглядит как и должно, у остальных как показано на картинке ниже.

```js
var deadline = new Date("2018, 7, 15 "); 
initializeClock('clock', deadline);

function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);


    if (t.total < 0) { 
      daysSpan.innerHTML = '00'
      hoursSpan.innerHTML = '00';
      minutesSpan.innerHTML = '00';
      secondsSpan.innerHTML = '00';
      return;
    }
    daysSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.days).slice(-2)
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total == 0) { 
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      alert('Times UP~');
    }
  }
  if (daysSpan <= 0 && hoursSpan <= 0 && minutesSpan <= 0 && secondsSpan <= 0) {
    console.log('sdfsdf');
  } else {
    updateClock();
    var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="stock text-center" id="stockDown">
       Акция закончится через
       <span id="clock">
        <span class="days"></span>:<span class="hours"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>    
       </span>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я Вас люблю! Ваша вера в нас меня восхищает.

Comment: Можно больше конкретики? И без стеба

Comment: Напрягитесь и представьте, что Вы ничего не знаете о Вашей задаче. Некто задает Вам вопрос в том виде, как это сделали Вы. Какие у некта шансы получить полезный ответ?

Comment: Где код, где что-нибудь ?

Comment: Мне хотя бы узнать как загуглить что это и из-за чего может это происходить, я не прошу сделать работающий таймер.

Comment: А мы просим вас показать код неработающего таймера. Это может происходить из-за чего угодно

Comment: Хорошо. В Вашем коде переменные, которые Вы считаете числами, содержат значения `NaN` - `Not a Number`.

Comment: Извиняюсь что сразу все не показал, мой косяк. Все добавлено

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я могу знать.

Потому что на некоторых телефонах строка, которую Вы подаете как параметр в `new Date()`, не является правильным строковым представлением даты.

А `parse` тут зачем?

```
var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
```

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = endtime - new Date();
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

// Учтите, что индекс месяца в такой форме создания объекта Date начинается с нуля.
var deadline = new Date(2018, 6/* July */, 15);
console.log(getTimeRemaining(deadline));
```

Comment: Код сразу становится не рабочим, если я передаю не строку

Comment: @Zebren какую ошибку пишет?

Comment: Неправильно высчитывает время, оно становится очень большим https://jsfiddle.net/Zebren/qdn2emzu/33/

Comment: @Zebren Вы опять? На что в Вашем мозгу отображается определение "становится нерабочим", мне знать не дано.

Comment: Я это уже понял, нельзя ли как-то этого избежать? Чтобы он начинался с 1, а не с 0

Comment: @Zebren Можно. Вычитайте из номера месяца единицу, чтобы получить индекс месяца.

Comment: Ок, спасибо большое, но не нужно к людям относится с излишней агрессией, люди разные бывают.

Comment: @Zebren Пожалуйста. Успехов. P.S. Не указывайте мне, как относиться к людям, и я отвечу на еще какой-нибудь Ваш вопрос.